# Python библиотеки для обучения и генерирования изображений нейросетью

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Подскажите библиотеки которые нужны для обучения и генерирования изображений нейросетью на Python и желательно какую то инструкцию с примерами, например что бы можно было обучить на фото котов и чтоб нейросеть потом генерировала их. модули и статьи с примерами кода.

Comment: Go to google...

Comment: @Александр как же вы догадались... в гугле я ничего не нашел...

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, в гугле полно информации о нейросетях на пайтон-е, даже с нуля есть гайды, а так гуглите tensorflow, pytorch, на сайте pytorch отличные примеры пошаговые, документация тоже на высоте.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос прекрасно гуглится, но на всякий случай оставляю вот это https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmgeneration - куча сеток, начиная от достаточно старых классик DCGAN и заканчивая свежими StyleGANv3 и т.д. Ещё есть такое - https://github.com/POSTECH-CVLab/PyTorch-StudioGAN. Короче говоря, читайте, находите видеокарту и будет вам счастье